# How to store comments in a site?

Tags: mysql, database

I have a site with login system. Any user who logged can make a comment. How should I store comments? What is the best method to store them, in mysql database or a txt file or something else? What kind of design do you recommend?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about

```
CREATE  TABLE login_comment (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `user_id` INT NOT NULL ,
  `timestamp` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp ,
 `comment` TEXT NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`) );
```

and you should also add a foreign key for the `user_id` to your `users` table.

Answer (score 0):

I would combine HTML, PHP and MySQL. User writes comment in HTML form, POST to a php file which in turn inserts comments in a MySQL database as @juergen d described above.